# Watchman installation error

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04, configure, watchman

I started installing all I need according to react-native Get Started guide. 
I installed Watchman and according to there [guide](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source). 
I got following error while running `./configure` command.

```
arafath@dell-pc:~/watchman$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

OS - UBUNTU 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded in installing following things.

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libssl-dev libtool
```